# Table of Contents shows abstract and acknowledgments on the same line

Tags: tocloft

[![add contents line does not work properly.][1]][1]

```
% ENGLISH ABSTRACT
\thispagestyle{plain}

\phantomsection

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}


\doublespacing
.
.
.
\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% TURKISH ABSTRACT
\thispagestyle{plain}

\phantomsection

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\"{O}ZET}

\doublespacing
.
.
.
.
\clearpage
```

The sections I add manually with \addcontentsline are listed on the samle line in the table of contents.

I am using these packages:

```
\usepackage{tocloft} %table of content requires this
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
%\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape}
```

Comment: The image of the problematic output appears to be missing. But even if it were visible, it would still be quite hard to help you, because the snippets of code posted so far do not constitute a compilable document. This means that we need to guess the rest of your setup and that means that we might guess wrong what is going on at your end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. The problem is I have never used “Chapter”.
When I changed everything with section it perfectly worked.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ABSTRACT}